# Rails App with Bootstrap Modal View containing form, submit and disappear modal view without reloading page

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have a rails app which presents a form for visitors in a modal view. When the submit button is clicked, I want the form to submit and the modal view to disappear without reloading the page behind it. I've tried binding the modal view's dismissal to the form's submit function in javascript, but it's not working correctly. I'm a javascript newbie, so I might not have scripted this correctly. Here's what I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("document").on("submit", ".new_user", function() {
        $('.signup').modal("close");
    });
</script>
<fieldset>

      <!-- The sign up modal view -->
       <div id="signup" class="modal hide fade in" style="display: none;">  
        <% @user = User.new %>
        <%= form_for(@user, :remote => true) do |f| %>
        <div class="modal-header">  
          <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>  
          <h3>Want to be notified when preorders start? Fill out this form!</h3>  
        </div>  
        <div class="modal-body">  
            <div class="field">
              <%= f.label :email %>
              <%= f.text_field :email, :class => 'modal_input'%>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
              <%= f.label :website %>
              <%= f.text_field :website, :class => 'modal_input'%>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
              <%= f.label :projects, "Projects you've worked on"  %>
              <%= f.text_area :projects, :size => "43x10", :class => 'modal_input' %>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">  
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
        </div>  
       </div>  
      <% end %>


       <!-- The modal view is triggered here -->
        <a data-toggle="modal" href="#signup" class="btn btn-primary
        btn-large btn-signup">Sign up</a>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  
        <script src="/twitter-bootstrap/twitter-bootstrap-v2/js/bootstrap-modal.js"></script>
  </fieldset>
```

My javascript function isn't closing the modal view. What's wrong with the function?

**EDIT**: Updated the javascript function, still not working correctly

**EDIT 2**: Turns out javascript function isn't being called at all, if that's any help.

Comment: Do you have a specific question? What does your script do right now?

Comment: Right now the script doesn't dismiss the modal view, but the form is submitted and the data is input into the database. I'm wondering what needs to be changed.

Answer (score 2):

`close()` is not a jQuery method and that is not how the Bootstrap modal library works. Also, the submit binding should be changed to be bound so that things inserted into the DOM after the binding has been setup.

You should probably change your function to something like this:

```
$(function () {
  $("document").on("submit", ".new_user", function() {
      $('.signup').modal("close");
  });
});
```

In addition, be sure that you have loaded in jQuery and the Bootstrap modal script files prior to this function.

Comment: Thanks for the input! Neither of those things made the modal view disappear. Any ideas?

Comment: Ok. Your problem may be that `$(".new_user")` is not actually mapping to the form in question. Are you sure that the rails form generator adds that class to the form?

Comment: It adds that ID I think. The opening HTML tag generated for the form is: `<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/users" class="new_user" data-remote="true" id="new_user" method="post">`

Comment: Ok. The more important question is whether or not your `submit` handler is actually getting called. Is it? If it isn't, then maybe the rails.js kills the submit event with the `data-remote="true"`.

Comment: I'm not sure if the handler is getting called (probably because I don't have a good understanding of what that means), but I know that the data is added to the database correctly.

Comment: If you change it to `$(".new_user").submit(function(){console.log("foobar");});` Does `foobar` show up in the console?

Comment: Ok. Pretty sure I know the problem. The way Bootstrap modals work is be removing and reinserting into the DOM the modal. So what this means is that the event handler is not bound. I'll modify the answer to be a fix.

Comment: Ignore my last comment, I forgot about another line I had changed. The updated function didn't change the behavior.

Comment: Ok. Another though. If the above is your actual code, you are loading in jQuery after you have already attempted to use it. Try moving the script tag that loads jQuery to before the event binding. You should also wrap the binding execution into a function that delays execution until document ready. (Adjusted answer above).